# Google Latitude API with HTTP?

Tags: https, oauth-2.0, google-latitude

This might be the stupiest question of the day but does Google Latitudes API work with unsecured pages, HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Latitude API works over HTTPS only, but you can certainly have an application that makes requests to the Latitude API, and then returns results on HTTP pages.